# ¿Comó puedo permitir que spring security me deje actualizar una pagina sinsacarme de la sesión?

Tags: jsp, spring, spring-security

tengo un problema al actualizar una pagina jsp ya que cuando lo hago spring security me manda a la pagina de login, saben como puedo quitar que cuado se actualize una pagina no me mande a login. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo pasar y leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para comprender como funciona el sitio.